# How document build options AND defines with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen, preprocessor

Question context:

doxygen 1.8.14 / Eclipse CDT 2021-03 / Eclox 0.12.1 / macOS 10.15.7

The project is plain C, and configured for that.

The question relates to the autogenerated documentation just from the bare code, not any comment markup of my own.

---

In Doxygen, with `Enable Preprocessing` YES, it analyses conditional build flags and doesn't document code inside those flags.

With `Enable Preprocessing` NO, Doxygen documents code inside those flags, but then doesn't document all the basic #define statements.

I don't understand this either/or opinion. I want both.

I've fiddled with all the preprocessing options (such as `Macro Expansion`) and cannot get what I need. It looks like I could manually list defines I want included, but for a 100k LOC project, that's not realistic.

Building multiple docs versions for every build variation where 97% of it is identical (while I see the usefulness for some people) would be a lame solution for my purposes -- the point of the docs is for the SW engineers to understand the whole system in context of the options, not exclusively one view of it.

Am I missing a config option somewhere which solves this? Thanks for reading.

```
// Examples (out of context):
//
// Build option system:

#define mBUILD_PLATFORM_105  (1U)
#define mBUILD_PLATFORM_205  (2U)
#define mBUILD_PLATFORM_300  (3U)
#define mBUILD_PLATFORM_320  (4U)
#define mBUILD_FOR_PLATFORM  (mBUILD_PLATFORM_105)

// Then in code somewhere...

#if (mBUILD_FOR_PLATFORM == mBUILD_PLATFORM_105)
// This could be a few lines, could be a whole function,
// or even a whole library suitable only for 105.
#endif

// Meanwhile, there are many of these...

#define mYADDA_SENSOR_COUNT_MAX  (12U)
```

Eclox UI preprocessor options:

[image: Eclox UI preprocessor options]

---

### Update 2:

```
// Differences from a baseline doxyfile (not including the obvious
// project-specific name, source path, etc.)

REPEAT_BRIEF           = NO
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       =
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = assets/mDoxStyles.css *
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 1
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = NO

// * I've made minor changes to text size, color and spacing.
//   Nothing structural.
```

---

### Update 3:

[image]

I'm using 4 files to try to explain. I've diagrammed these files, and hopefully it can be viewed at full scale so you can refer to it.

Start at the left with mProject.h -- this has the build defines I showed earlier, and for good measure another define along with "Dox-umentation" for the file and one define.

Next is mMutex.h which is facade API the programmer will use throughout the application. This also contains Dox-umentation for the file and a define.

The next two files mMutex_rtos and mMutex_macos are implementation details for the mMutex facade. Note the build conditional wrapping pretty much the whole file.

OK, so, what does Doxygen 1.8.14 do with these files...

I wrote these files in a simple text editor, and ran these files using the Doxygen GUI (no Eclipse or Eclox). The only Doxygen setting I'm playing with is ENABLE_PREPROCESSING and EXTRA_ALL. Note that the build conditional is set to mOS_MACOS.

With ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES and EXTRACT_ALL = YES

- Project.h -- All defines are documented (info rendered in the html file).
- mMutex.h -- The full file is processed and documented with the @file and @var info being rendered in the html file.
- mMutex_macos.h -- The file is fully documented and all details rendered in html.
- mMutex_rtos.h -- The file shows up in the file list, the html page shows only the #include, and no other documentation is rendered. If I set EXTRACT_ALL = NO, then the file name show up in the file list, but there is no link to a subsequent html page.

The problem I have in this scenario is that none of the content of the mMutex_rtos file is captured in the documentation. In this style where the build conditional is wrapping a whole file or whole functions, and not just a few lines inline in a function, then documentation ends up missing.

With ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = NO and EXTRACT_ALL = YES

- Project.h -- The @file info is rendered, bu none of the defines are included in the html file at all. Neither Dox's usual rendering, nor my explicit @var content are present.
- mMutex.h -- The functions are rendered with Dox's default content, but mMUTEX_NAME_LENGTH_MAX is missing from the html file. Neither Dox's usual rendering, nor my explicit @var content are present.
- mMutex_macos.h -- The file is fully documented and all details rendered in html. However, if there was a #define it, it would be missing.
- mMutex_rtos.h -- Now the file is fully documented and all details rendered in html. However, if there was a #define it, it would be missing.

What I notice with EXTRACT_ALL on/off is that it adds the the big tabbed-looking sections for defines and functions even if there is no @fn text of my own. Otherwise, when ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = Y, I don't think EXTRACT_ALL is changing what is being included in the html files.

So, it appears that I have a choice of eliminating all #defines (not an option), or excluding all documentation for a whatever build options are not active at the time the documentation is compiled.

(I will try 1.9.x at some point soon.)

---

- Updated to include context notes, some text edits, the Eclox UI image.
- Update 2 to include doxyfile differences.
- Update 3 to provide more detailed file examples.

Comment: Which doxygen version are you using? You mention `Enable preprocession` do you mean here the flag `MACRO_EXPANSION`? Your example doen't contain any documentation for doxygen, can you please add a small example together with the settings for doxygen that are different from the default settings (`doxygen -x`)?

Comment: @albert I updated the post with context details (sorry for that ambiguity). As for a sample, there's really no sample needed IMO as the problem isn't with any of my formatted commentary, it's based on raw source code and how Dox is reading that to generate its default output. Not sure yet how to collect project-specific settings to share. Will figure that out. Hoping the Eclox UI image helps.

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.14 is a bit older (December 2017), the current version is 1.9.1 so I certainly would advise to upgrade, but this is, most likely, not the cause of your problems. The shown settings just look like the default settings for the preprocessing group, but without the Doxyfile it is hard to tell (I don't know what Eclox does under he hood). I don't know whether or not  you set settings in other groups, but it is worthwhile to look at `EXTRACT_ALL` as in that case I see all defines, the part in the `#if` has nothing documentable / isn't documenting anything, so nothing can be shown either.

Comment: (Continued) There must be a Doxyfile somewhere written by eclox so you share the differences with the default version with us (for a complete picture of the case). Furthermore I would advise to look in the doxygen manual to get an impression of what all the possibilities are.

Comment: I started with 1.8.14, but later updates had bugs handling callback function prototypes, so I reverted to 1.8.14. My #if example says there would be code in there. I read the docs. The Preprocessing page makes sense. What I don't see is when `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` is NO, that even basic #define statements are ignored and left out of the docs. I can understand preprocessor evaluation being on/off, but that should not dissuade Dox from documenting the existence of basic define statements. I was expecting this to be a common setting I was just missing, but I guess not. Thx for trying to help.

Comment: You mentioned: " later updates had bugs handling callback function prototypes" is this in the 1.9.1 version still the case? If so please file a bug report in the doxygen github issue tracker.

Comment: @albert re: callback bug -- yes the bug still exists in 1.9.1. I -- I thought I reported it, and just found it -- [link] (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7060#issuecomment-567556453)

Comment: I see the issue and also that a proposed patch has been submitted but that in this pull request there has been some discussion as well.

Comment: I see that you wrote: "I'm using 4 files to try to explain. I've diagrammed these files, and hopefully it can be viewed at full scale so you can refer to it." this is a very bad idea as now it is not possible to do some easy tests and also the images are overlapping (probably the hidden text is  not relevant but still ...).

Comment: As I cannot test something maybe the `INCLUDE_PATH` setting might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but the results from testing the given information.

I dumped the provided code in a file aa.h and the  the provided settings (except the CSS settings) in a Doxyfile and ran with the versions 1.8.14 and 1.9.1

In both cases I got the same output:

[image]

And this looks, according to the given information, OK to me.
Do you miss something or did I overlook something?

Comment: I added Update 3 with more detailed file examples. I can try to zip up my sample files, Dox config, and some HTML screenshots if you'd like.